# Create horizontal line in discord message

Tags: discord, markdown

I would like to create a horizontal like in a `discord` message. Unfortunately using `markdown` doesn't work. For example, the syntax `***` doesn't return a horizontal line or any given option from [here](https://github.com/mattcone/markdown-guide/blob/master/_basic-syntax/horizontal-rules.md#). Here are some example I tried in a message:

[image]

My expected outcome would be like the lines from a new message per day like this:

[image]

So I was wondering if anyone knows if it is possible to create a horizontal line in a discord message?

Answer (score 1):

It may not be exactly what you look like but the best option to get a solution as near as possible would be using the ```` ``` ```` annotation of discord.

So you can get a result like this
[image]

(Here a list of other characters to use: https://www.symbolcopy.com/line-symbols.html)

Code:

````
```──────────────────────────────────────────────── 29. Januari 2024 ───────────────────────────────────────────────────```
````

In the ``` annotation you can use several styling option. The documentation for this is not really good in my opinion but the best resource for this is in my opinion: https://www.writebots.com/discord-text-formatting/

I hope this helps you a bit